# How can I get the values from a python dictionary to a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I've been trying to get a report which is a dictionary, in a CSV file. But just the values, excluding the keys. This is my dictionary.

This is an example of one.

Dictionary:

```
{'Type': 'XXXXXX', 'InvoiceID': '123456', 'InvoiceNumber': '001', 'Reference': '', 'Payments': [{'PaymentID': '12345678910', 'BatchPaymentID': '12345678910', 'Date': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 31, 0, 0), 'Amount': 1000, 'Reference': '', 'CurrencyRate': 1.0, 'HasAccount': False, 'HasValidationErrors': False}]
```

This is the code I'm using.

```py
def get(report,month):
    my_dict = report


    with open('invoices.csv','w') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the error messages says, your "dict" is actually a ``list``. The cause of the problem is not in the code you are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the dictionary to a dataframe and then write it into csv.

**Code:**

```py
my_dict={'Type': 'XXXXXX', 'InvoiceID': '123456', 'InvoiceNumber': '001', 'Reference': '', 'Payments': [{'PaymentID': '12345678910', 'BatchPaymentID': '12345678910', 'Date': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 31, 0, 0), 'Amount': 1000, 'Reference': '', 'CurrencyRate': 1.0, 'HasAccount': False, 'HasValidationErrors': False}]}

df=pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.to_csv('invoices.csv',index=None,header=None, mode='w')   #add header=None to exclude the keys. Mode can be changed depending on whether you want to write or append.
```

**Output:**

```
    Type    InvoiceID   InvoiceNumber   Reference   Payments
0   XXXXXX  123456      001                         {'PaymentID': '12345678910', 'BatchPaymentID':...
```